# how to do single-sign-on (SSO) between two web apps, PHP and Java EE?

Tags: php, jakarta-ee, single-sign-on

I have an existing Java EE web application running on GlassFish 3.1.  Sign in works fine through the jdbcRealm configured in GlassFish 3.1.

Someone on another team is developing a separate web application in PHP, the boss doesn't want the user of the apps to have to sign in twice.  That is, when they are signed in to the Java web app and they click a link that takes them to the PHP app, they should already be signed in to that app as well.  (And vice-versa.)

Not sure how to implement this.  I was thinking that I could generate a long random key (a token) that gets generated on log in of either app, and passed around in every web request for either app to identify a logged in user, but that doesn't seem safe.

I need pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said

> I was thinking that I could generate a long random key (a token) that
>   gets generated on log in of either app, and passed around in every web
>   request for either app to identify a logged in user, but that doesn't
>   seem safe.

But that's essentially how sessions work.

Your best bet is to generate a unique login identifier (as you said) store it in a database or memory cache accessible by both apps and find a way to save it such that both web apps can retrieve it.

If both apps are on same root domain, you can use a cookie with path set to `/` so both apps can access it.

If both apps are going to be on different root domain then it will be a little more tricky.

As for security regarding the identifier token being passed around, you could regenerate the identifier on each request, which guards against cookie jacking.

Comment: regenerating a sessionId on each request will not work because of the asynchronous nature of HTTP requests.

Comment: @Jacco For this case the solution I came up with was to use 2 session ids, one current and one previous. And every 60 seconds I generated a new session ID and set the previous to current, and current to the new one. I used a MySQL Db for storing sessions so this was easy, as i stored a last generated time, and used that to regenerate the id. This way the requests in the pipeline are still considered authentic for 60 seconds with the previous id. Or if possible you can just use SSL and forget about cookie/session jacking.

Comment: I see; does it not generate false positives/negatives ?

Comment: @Jacco No there are no false positives/negatives if implemented correctly. I can give a sample database driven implementation in my answer if you want one. So do you want to allow login from multiple places at the same time (e.g. in gmail) or not ? This would be essential for designing a database system for this. Also you can use a memory cache like Memcache if performance is paramount.