# login system in java HttpURLConnection and php server

Tags: java, php, mysql, httpurlconnection

I have a little program in JAVA, and i want to make a login system but not connected directly to database.
I want, first goes to a program in php and then php connected with mysql
in my php server i have:

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

 $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'persec');
if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){
    $username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    $pass = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM acesso WHERE username='$username'";

    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

    header("Content-Type:text/plain");
    http_response_code(200)

    if($result->num_rows === 1){
        $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])){
             $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

         echo "true";
        }else{
            echo "false";
        }
```

?>

and now, I have this in Java

```
String username = txtUser.getText(); 
            String password = new String(txtpass.getPassword());    
            try {
                String urlParam = "u="+username+"&p="+password;
                byte[] postData = urlParam.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                int postDataLength = postData.length;
                URL url = new URL("http://localhost/dashboard3/loginServer.php");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                conn.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postDataLength));
                conn.setUseCaches(false);
                try( DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream())) {
                       wr.write( postData );
                       System.out.println(postData);
                    }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }catch (IOException e1){
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I think everything is fine, know..the question is:
How can I get from Java the confirmation in php if i can make login or not?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570101/how-to-do-single-sign-on-sso-between-two-web-apps-php-and-java-ee maybe this will help you

Comment: Tips: You can try to use [InputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getInputStream()) from the `HttpUrlConnection` to read what the php server return.

Answer (score 0):

If you return "true" or "false" in the body of your http response, then you can add this code to what you already have, and it will read a line from the input stream.

```
try( DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream())) {
    wr.write( postData );
    System.out.println(postData);
} catch (Exception e) { ... }

...

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String responseMsg = in.readLine();

if( responseMsg != null){
    System.out.println(responseMsg);
}
in.close();
...
```